# Are $\xi \cdot \hat{u}(\xi)$ and $e^x \cdot u(x)$ bounded in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, schwartz-space

Given a function $u(x) \in \mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R})$, I would like to establish if:

1. $\xi \cdot \hat{u}(\xi)$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$, where $\hat{u}(\xi)$ is the Fourier transform of $u$
2. $e^x \cdot u(x)$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$

but I don't know how to approach the problem.

For part 1, I tried to use that Fourier transform is always bounded with $\Vert{\hat{u}}\Vert_{\infty} \le \Vert{u}\Vert_{L^1} $ and in this case $u \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ but multiplying any $u$ by $\xi$ the result is yet bounded? And the same doubts arose with part two.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you in advance

Comment: 1. Note that $u’(x)$ is in $L^1$. 2. Consider $f(x)=\exp\left[-(1+|x|^2)^{1/3}\right]$.

Comment: $u'(x)$ is in $L^1$ because $(x^2+1)u'(x)$ is bounded. The next step is to take $h$ any continuous function which isn't bounded by a polynomial and ask if there exists $u$ Schwartz such that $hu$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the Fourier transform is actually an automorphism on the Schwartz space, then the first assertion follows pretty much by the definition (or a equivalent characterization) of a Schwartz function, that is, $\varphi$ is in $\mathcal{S}$ if and only if 
$$ \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |x^m D^n\varphi(x)| < \infty \qquad \text{for all} \quad n,m \in \mathbb{N}_0,$$
where $D^n$ refers to the $n$-th derivative (so $D^n \varphi (x) = \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\varphi(x)$ and $D^0\varphi =\varphi$). If you don't know the fact about the Fourier transform being an automorphism on the Schwartz function, you can also get this first result "by hand" by using the following fact: If $\varphi$ is a Schwartz function then there exist for any positive integers $N$ and $m$ a constant $C_{N,m}$ such that
$$ 
|D^m\varphi(x)| \leq C_{N,m} (1+|x|)^{-N}.
$$
Indeed, this actually is another characterization of the Schwartz functions (one that I found to be quite useful). And it is this rapid decay to zero of any Schwartz function at infinity (among other things) that is used to show that $\widehat{\varphi}$ is again a Schwartz function.

This also relates a bit to the second questions, since it is at least true that any Schwartz functions decays to zero quicker than any polynomial.

Finally, with these tools at hand and the comments by *reuns* (below) and *Mindlack* one can also show the first assertion quite elegantly.

Comment: I don't think so. I think you can estimate the expression directly.

Comment: Sure but I'm quite sure the OP didn't realize $2i\pi\xi \hat{u}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u'(x)e^{-2i\pi \xi x}dx$ so he needs $|u'(x)| \leq C (1+|x|)^{-2}$

Comment: But that is just one way to do it, right? - A very nice way indeed! But I thought I can provide a different inside. But thanks for making the other argument clear.

Comment: I don't see any alternative :o)

Comment: I think the other way would be to use the fact that the Fourier transform of a Schwartz function is again a Schwartz function. (I only made this into an answer because I wasn't allowed to just comment yet). But I see now that my second statement isn't useful very much. Thanks for making me aware of that! I will edit it.

Comment: @hal4math so, $\hat{\phi}(x)$ is Schwartz means that if I multiply it by any polynomial the result is bounded, so $\xi \hat{\phi}(\xi)$ is bounded, right? And for the second part I don't understand what "any Schwartz functions decays to zero quicker than any polynomial." has to do with it. Do you mean that $e^x$ is not a polynomial so $e^x u(x)$ cannot be bounded? Can you explain?

Comment: Yes, to your first statement. The other argument I just added it to maybe give an intuition about how these functions behave. Though, I think _Mindlack_ nailed it with his counterexample. Does this makes it clearer?